# Finding the intensity of the electrostatic field of a point using Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: electrostatics

So my professor drew the following picture:

[image]

And then she wrote (obviously explained it as well) that the intensity of the electrostatic field of the point $P$ is:

$E_p=\sqrt{E_1^2+2E_1E_2\cos\angle(E_1,E_2)+E_2^2}$.

But her explanation went completely over my head. She said something about rotating the angle between vectors $\overrightarrow{E_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{E_2}$ in order to put it into a coordinate plane, and somehow came up with this equation. I think she might have used the Pythagorean theorem but I really cannot see how it could be used here since there is no right angle being formed between the vectors. Can somebody clarify how she could've come up with this formula?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the formula $\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} = A B \cos \angle(A,B)$?

Comment: @Andrew that should be the cross product formula, right?

Comment: It's a formula for the dot product.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines